# How to use Sqlite.Callback in Genie

Tags: sqlite, genie

While trying to solve the question [How to print a sqlite table content with genie programming language](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33446085/how-to-print-a-sqlite-table-content-with-genie-programming-language) I found out that I could try to call PrintSingleRecipe as a callback from Database.exec. However, it seems that a callback cannot be a regular function, they have some property that I do not seem to find over in the internets.

I am calling it in this way:

```
else if response is "3" //Show a Recipe
    res:string = UserInterface.raw_input("Select a recipe -> ")
    sql:string = "SELECT * FROM Recipes WHERE pkID = %res"
    db.exec(sql, PrintSingleRecipe, null)
```

And the function itself looks like:

```
def PrintSingleRecipe(n_columns:int, values:array of string, column_names:array of string)
    print "~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~"
    for i:int = 0 to n_columns
        stdout.printf ("%s = %s\n", column_names[i], values[i])
    print "~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~"
    print "Ingredient list"
    print " "
    stdout.printf("%-5s", "%03i" )
```

However, I get the following error at compilation:

```
valac --pkg sqlite3 --pkg gee-0.8 cookbook.gs
cookbook.gs:42.26-42.42: error: Argument 2: Cannot convert from `PrintSingleRecipe' to `Sqlite.Callback?'
            db.exec(sql, PrintSingleRecipe, null)
                         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
Compilation failed: 1 error(s), 0 warning(s)
```

How to properly run the callback in Genie?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Vala compiler does type checking on a function when a function is passed as a parameter. When a function is used in this way it is called a "delegate". Specifically the Vala compiler will check that the function's signature matches the signature of the delegate type definition. A function's signature is made up of its parameter types and return type. `Cannot convert from 'PrintSingleRecipe' to 'Sqlite.Callback?'` means the `PrintSingleRecipe` function's signature doesn't match the `Sqlite.Callback` delegate definition's signature.

The Sqlite.Callback delegate definition is shown here:
http://valadoc.org/#!api=sqlite3/Sqlite.Callback
You have rightly identified the parameters required are `int, array of string, array of string`, but you also need to include the return type. In this case it is an `int`. So your callback should look like:

```
def PrintSingleRecipe(n_columns:int, 
        values:array of string, 
        column_names:array of string
        ):int
    print "~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~"
    for i:int = 0 to n_columns
        stdout.printf ("%s = %s\n", column_names[i], values[i])
    print "~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~"
    print "Ingredient list"
    print " "
    stdout.printf("%-5s", "%03i" )
    return 0
```

Returning non-zero will abort the query. See https://www.sqlite.org/capi3ref.html#sqlite3_exec

Comment: Hi AIThomas, how to call the variable res from the sql string? The syntax that I used do not work: ```res:string = UserInterface.raw_input("Select a recipe -> ")
            sql:string = "SELECT * FROM Recipes WHERE pkID = %res"```

Comment: You can use string concatenation: `sql:string = "SELECT * FROM Recipes WHERE pkID = " + res`
or a template: `sql:string = @"SELECT * FROM Recipes WHERE pkID = $res"`